# Reverse tick order

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

With radar charts is it possible to have the order be reversed? For example have 10 being closest to the center and 1 being furthest away from the center for values that are 1 through 10?

Answer (score 0):

To reverse the radar chart as you described:

```
type: 'radar',
data: {...},
options: {
    scale: {
        ticks: {
            reverse: true,
            beginAtZero: false,
            min: 1
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to the doc [Styling](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html) and [Linear Radial Axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html).